# Linked get company news API Access token reset every 60 day's?

Tags: php, mysql, linkedin-api

I am using one of Linked-In PHP API for getting company news, but I have face problem like I need every 60 day's re-login because I got Error for Access Token Expired. what I do like I need to create any different type account for never expiry access token or Any process for update automatically Access token.

Comment: Why don't you just re-login to get a new token on every 59th day?

Comment: Can you write here code for get how many days reaming ?